# How to run store procedures simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm doing a job to tuning some store procedures got situation like this:

there is a procedure let's call it sp_summary it will do some prepare work first and then it will exec like 10 procedures in serial. basically it's :

```
   create procedure sp_summary(date datetime)
    as 
     Begin
      Declare @v1 varchar(10)
      .....
      .....
      exec sp_sub_1
      exec sp_sub_2
      ....
      exec sp_sub_10
      ....
      ....
    End
```

almost each of them will cost like 2 minutes and 20 for total, and all their doing is just create a temp talbe catch some data from source table and calculate some columns then insert into the target table.

the question is:

how to exec the 10 sub sps simultaneously to make the 20 minutes per day become like 2 or 5 mins per day. And since all 10 sub sps got same source table and same target table, how to do the Transaction Isolation to avoid create dirty data.

P.S: Informatica or SSIS or other ETL tools are not an option. Any DBMS solution would be great

Comment: You missed to tag a few dbms products...

Comment: only could add 5 tags i think these are good enough

Comment: jarls's comment was ironic :-) Your syntax implies SQL Server and not MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke is it mysql or sql-server? Remove the tags that are not appropriate

Comment: @CiucaS i'm thinking this question for all those 3 dbms, the this is in SQLSERVER, but we also got Oracle and Mysql might have the same situation,so any answer for any dbms would be greate

Comment: @dnoeth lol, i just want know if we use Oracle or Mysql or SQLSERVER what should we do to solve this, i m just curious. I met this before in Oracle and we use Informatica to solved it and now i met it again in SQLSERVER :(

Comment: For SQL Server this can be done using Service Broker (afaik Oracle got something similar), but it's overly complicated, google for "parallel execution service broker". A generic solution for all DBMSes would need 1 session per CALL

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks! that really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Oracle** you could use **[DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm)**.

For example,

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
  3      job_name        => 'test_full_job_definition',
  4      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5      job_action      => 'BEGIN my_job_procedure; END;',
  6      start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  7      repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
  8      end_date        => NULL,
  9      enabled         => TRUE,
 10      comments        => 'Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.');
 11  END;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You could schedule all your procedures to execute simultaneously instead of executing them procedural way one after another.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple jobs to execute each of your stored procedure. Schedule all your jobs run at the same time.

Say J1 to J10 are your jobs then all your jobs should run at the same time.

Create one more job for prepare work and schedule it few minutes before your previous scheduled job time.

Comment: that is an option. is there a way to solve this in 1 job?

Comment: As far as my knowledge there are two ways, 
1.Create a SSIS job to run the 5 stored procedures in parallel.
2.Create 5 different SQL Server Agent jobs scheduled at the same time

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in the SQL code directly as its nature is serial. You will have to use divide and win approach here. For this you can either use Service broker/sql agent/SSIS.

1. Service Broker: You can set up queues, service, activation procedures and set max queue readers as 10. This will setup the queue to fetch 10 tasks simulateneously. In the activation procedure, you can execute the required procedure. Basically, the message should contain the SQL you want to run.
2. SQL Agent: You can create 10 sql agent jobs that check a same table (table a) for incoming work. Each job will cater to one record from table at a time and continue to do so untill table is empty. Create another procedure that inserts 10 rows containing 10 SQL calls in "table a" and kick off all 10 sql agents jobs.
3. Use SSIS as suggested by one responder above

IMO: I have always chosen service broker as it is more sclable.